# Hyper-V server 2019 - Allow Hyper-V Manager through the firewall

Tags: windows

My Problem:

- When enabling firewall I lose connection to the Hyper-V server via Hyper-V Manager
- when disabling the firewall I can connect to the Hyper-V server via Hyper-V Manager

My Environment:

- Windows 10 PRO client
- Windows Server 2019 Hyper-V host
- Hyper-V Manager
- Hyper-V Server is outside of the local network
- RDP possible

I have tried:

- Enable-PSRemoting
- Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role server
- Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup 'Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)' -Enabled true -PassThru
- Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup 'Remote Event Log Management' -Enabled true -PassThru
- Enabling  Configure Remote Management

Answer (score 0):

Well when it comes to firewall it's mostly about enabling the related ports. I suggest something like this:

> For workgroup-joined machines, your best option is to locate the
> firewall rules in the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security tool
> that match the remote management tool(s) you wish to use and
> selectively open them to the necessary remote IP addresses. If you’re
> using hardware firewalls, Microsoft does not publish all necessary
> ports to be opened. These are typically within the first few ports in
> the dynamic range (49152 and higher), but they do change.
>
> The most critical ports to open are 135 (RPC endpoint mapper) and 5985
> (WSMan). If you’ll be taking the extra step of sending WSMan traffic
> through an encrypted connection, that will move across port 5986. Be
> aware that this provides little extra security. The only portion of
> standard WSMan traffic that is not encrypted is initial negotiation.

From here: https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/how-to-set-up-hyper-v-remote-management/

or

> Opened up ports 135, 2179, and 49152-65535 did a trick for me.

from here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/858c55aa-4ae2-4804-b16d-8ea5c929f9c9/hyperv-remote-management-specific-ports?forum=winserverhyperv